# If there is a high correlation between two variables, should we expect the high linear regression coefficient?

Tags: regression, correlation

I have a data set with multiple features, let suppose $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ and my dependent variable is $y$, when I compute the correlation matrix for $y,x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ then imagine the correlation coefficient for the first row and column is lookalike [1,0.2,-0.8,0.01,0.9], should I expect a high linear coefficient for variables $x_2$ and $x_4$?

Comment: No, not necessarily, correlation is univariate, (multiple) linear regression is not, and the results might differ.

Comment: Not only shouldn't you have any expectations for the regression coefficients, you also shouldn't draw any conclusions from a model set up with these variables, since you are violating one of the main prerequisites for linear regression. See https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-collinearity-in-regression-fe7a2c1467ea, http://r-statistics.co/Assumptions-of-Linear-Regression.html

Comment: You should expect a negative correlation between $x_2$ and $x_4$, I think between $-0.458$ and $-0.982$.  But there will be examples where the linear regression coefficients appear small in magnitude, for example when the variances of  $x_2$ and $x_4$ are much larger than the variance of $y$; even if that is not the case, there will be other examples where at least one has a small linear regression coefficient

Comment: @rumtscho Lack of feature multicollinearity is not an assumption of linear regression, and that article you've linked glosses over complex issues of modeling. See, for instance, [my answer here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555145/ridge-regression-for-multicollinearity-and-outliers/555163?r=SearchResults#555163) about why discarding correlated features can be dangerous. // It is a common misconception to think that lacking feature correlation is an assumption of linear regression; I think this comes from misinterpreting the lack of error correlation in the Gauss-Markov theorem.