# How to select features while keeping covariates in mlr3

Tags: feature-selection, mlr

I am doing a classification job using `mlr3`. There are several covariates besides independent variables (features) in my dataset. I wonder how to select a feature subset and keep all the covariates. For example, here is a simple dataset where V1-V3 are independent variables, PC1 and PC2 are covariates. How to select variables among V1-V3 and keep PC1 and PC2 in the final dataset for training?

```
> data.frame(V1=1:4,V2=5:8,V3=9:12,PC1=rnorm(4),PC2=rnorm(4),Target=c("A","A","B","B"))
  V1 V2 V3         PC1        PC2 Target
1  1  5  9  0.03192998  0.3418128      A
2  2  6 10 -1.60314372  0.2134503      A
3  3  7 11 -0.90306085 -1.5662568      B
4  4  8 12 -1.42996139 -0.9007882      B
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1) Why not just select them? // 2) [Why select at all?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/555145/ridge-regression-for-multicollinearity-and-outliers/555163?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C47.0352#555163)

Comment: Hi,@Dave, Thanks for your quick comment! For your first question, if the best subset obtained from `mlr3` filter or selector is, for instance, V1, V2 and PC1, do you mean I can keep PC2 manually? For the second question, I select features to optimize model performance.

Comment: Did you read my linked post about the dangers of feature selection?

Comment: I have to confess I just read your linked post. I will try regularization then. Thank you for your advice! @Dave