# A quick question about correlation

Tags: correlation, python

If **A** (density of a material) and **B** (solid volume of a material=mass/density) are highly correlated features, how to decide which one of these two features shall I drop?

After normalization, feature **A** consists of two values, either 0 or 1 (I have only used 2 materials in my model), but feature **B** consists of more than 5 values.

My guess is to keep feature **B** due to its high variance.

Comment: [Why drop either feature? Nothing says that regression features have to be independent.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/555163/247274)

Comment: Regression features should not be [multicollinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity). They can be, and in fact often are, dependent.