# Cutoff For Correlation to Considered as Multicollinearity

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, mixed-model

If one variable is correlated to other 73% or between (70% to 75%) does it should be considered as multicollinearity and shall I exclude one of the variable from linear regression model ?
I will be very thankful if you also provide justification of your answer.

Comment: [Related](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/555163/247274) // Why drop any variables at all?

Comment: Comments: Such recipes for dropping variables are crude at best, silly at worst. There are many other things to consider. Also,  correlation is not a %.